# Background image is too big

Tags: image, resize, background-image

I have problem with background image on my website. 
So, the image size is 7.8MB and resolution is 5616 × 3744.

When page loads it's too longs, so I am wondering what are the best solutions how I can modify my bg image ?

Best Regards,
Bojan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ImagemMgick` to make your image smaller - it is installed on most Linux distros and available for free for all good OSes (and Windows) from [here](http://www.imagemagick.org).

Say you want it to be no more than 1024 pixels wide, you would do

```
convert BigBoy.jpg -resize 1024x BabyBackground.jpg
```

You could also reduce the quality a little to make it smaller by adding in a quality setting like this:

```
convert BigBoy.jpg -resize 1024x -quality 80% BabyBackground.jpg
```

If your image is a regular pattern, you could use CSS styling to `tile` the image to cover the background

```
body {
    background-image: url("gradient_bg.png");
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
}
```

See [here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_background.asp) for explanation and example.

Answer (score 0):

Resize your background image before uploading it to your server.